# x86 Far return mnemonic in Clang 9/GCC assembler?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, clang, att

I'm trying to write a piece of x86 assembly code in .S file that I compile with Clang 9.
I need to use "far return imm16" instruction in my code, I tried to use "retf" with or without an immediate operand, but the compiler doesn't recognize it and gives me "`error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'retf'`". It only recognizes "ret" and "retn".

What am I doing wrong? What is correct mnemonic that I need to use?

Comment: They relevant search term is "AT&T syntax" or "gnu assembler", not "clang / gcc".  clang's built-in assembler is compatible with GAS.  GCC just runs GAS on `.s` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mnemonic is `lret`.  Use it like this:

```
lret $0x1234
```

For future questions like this, you can always assemble a file in Intel syntax:

```
.syntax intel,noprefix

        retf 0x1234
```

and then disassemble it with `objdump` to get the AT&T syntax for the instruction:

```
   0:   ca 34 12                lret   $0x1234
```